# How do I route this pin on USB-C?

Tags: usb, usb-c

I'm having trouble determining how to route this trace for this USB-C component. I have asked a few sources, but nobody seems to know. (This USB-C is only being used for USB 2.0 D+/D- & charging capability, but to use the physical capabilities of USB-C for a personal/hobby project)

Amphenol UC-31PFFH-QF7001

[image]

This may look like a duplicate question from one I posted before, but after getting the board made, I discovered that the dimension was wrong and the USB-C would not fit without grinding away the notch further into the PCB.  The result is what you see in this picture above now.  With the modified dimension, I can no longer route CC2 the way you currently see it.

Comment: Is this a 2 layer board or more?

Comment: @RonBeyer it is a 4 layer board

Comment: Have you tried sneaking it through on L2 or L3?

Comment: @RonBeyer Even with a 3 mil trace I couldn't get it through based on my DRC, but I'll see if I my fab house can squeeze things just a lil more

Comment: If you don't have enough layers to fan-out this footprint, you need to use a different kind of connector, without the deep cut-out.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I'm sorry, but I don't see how the amount of layers has any impact on routing this pin, particularly beyond 4 layers.

Comment: You have two holes 0.4mm in diameter, spaced at 0.8 mm. Technically you have 0.4mm channel, since you don't have to keep antipads on internal layers of the same size as on external layers. Still you need more than 4 layers with this cut-outs, since you need to keep two ground reference planes.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem on a 2 bond Flexi Rigid, my initial thought was to remove unused pads on inner layers and sneak a 100um trace between but our Fab house would class this a R&D as the annulus was too tight 0.4mm finished plated hole drilled at 0.5mm (Plated hole to track 100um/4 thou and annular ring of only 75um /3 thou) will almost certainly reduce yields & possibly end in 100% scrap

Our Solution:

[image]

Short together B3 and B5 on inner layer, then only use USBC, USBA and USBC 2.0 for data transfer. These cables don't wire up pins B10,B11,A2,A3,A11,A10,B2,B3.

Comment: This is awesome, I was tempted to do this.  It confuses me that Amphenol would make this connector without having fully thought out the routing, and possibly even have a design reference to use..  but, that's a pipe dream I suppose lol.  I ended up doing something (sorta?) similar, but I physically removed the outter pin with some tweezers. and removed the hole from the footprint.That only works for small batches though in which a person can remove that single pin.